# BenQ 2480 brightness

Tags: display

Bought a BenQ 2480 monitor and I would like to change monitor brightness through it's built in function, however it's grayed out. Also had a BenQ 2470 where this option worked fine. Thank you for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind, found out I had to disable the setting Bright Intelligence.

Edit: You can turn this setting off by pressing one of the 5 monitor buttons to the left of the power button. going to the settings (4th button from the right) going into the first option (Eye Care) and then select the first option again (Bright Intelligence) which you turn off. 
BE CAREFUL you have to apply the settings (check-mark) before you close the options.

Comment: It would be even better if you would [edit] your answer to be more detailed.  How and where do you access this setting?  Is it in the operating system somewhere (GUI? CLI?), in BIOS, or a hardware switch?